# Can't select a child node within the Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML piece of code

```
<div id="countdown">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="giorni"><span class="num red">66</span><span class="lab">Giorni</span></li>
                        <li id="ore"><span class="num red">23</span><span class="lab">Ore</span></li>
                        <li id="minuti"><span class="num red">44</span><span class="lab">Minuti</span></li>
                        <li id="secondi"><span class="num red">14</span><span class="lab">Secondi</span></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

I want to replace the content of each span that has a num class. In order to do that I have written:

```
var countdown = {
        init: function( config ) {
            this.dataX = Date.parse(new Date(2012, 5, 30));
            this.adesso = new Date().getTime();
            this.giorni = config.container.find('li#giorni');
            console.log(this.giorni);
            this.count();
        },
                ... some other code ...
};

countdown.init({
   container: $('div#countdown ul');
});
```

I really don't understand why if I try to log `this.giorni` I get `[]` in response, but if I write into the console the same code it returns the node I need.

Comment: Is `<div id="countdown">` inside `<div id="container">`?

Comment: Do you run the script after the document is loaded? If not, tags may simply not exist yet. try `jQuery(document).ready(function($){..your code here..});`

Comment: try to run `countdown.init` when the document has finished loading. It is posibile that the element you are looking for doesn't exist yet at the moment you call init.

Comment: @Armatus I'm sorry it's `container: $('div#countdown ul')`, my bad.

Comment: Are you sure you execute `countdown.init` once your DOM is loaded ?

Comment: Make sure the DOM is loaded before you run init, it works fine on fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/AS63g/

Comment: @Miszy that's it!! thank you, I haven't thought of that. Rookie learns another lesson!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#countdown span.num').each(function() {
    $(this).empty().html(Math.random() * 1000);
});
```